# How do I load a file into list then in to a listbox using FileStream C#?

Tags: c#, load, external, filestream

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFeNX.jpg)

The Picture above just shows the code below, you can use either to help me with my nightmare at moment. Thanks lads

```
List<IpayableStaff> employeeList = new List<IpayableStaff>();

private void LoadData()
        {
            FileStream inFile;
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                inFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                while (inFile.Position < inFile.Length)
                {
                    IpayableStaff load = (IpayableStaff)bformatter.Deserialize(inFile);
                    employeeList.Add(load);
                    lstEmployees.Items.Add(load);
                }

                inFile.Close();
            }
        }

private void SaveData()
{        
    FileStream outFile;

    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    if (lstEmployees.Items.Count > 0)
        {
          //opening the file in order to write in to it
          outFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

         for (int i = 0; i < lstEmployees.Items.Count; i++)
         {
            //write on file via serialization
            bformatter.Serialize(outFile, lstEmployees.Items[i]);
         }

          //closing the file
          outFile.Close();
     }
 }
```

**There is an error but I can not see it, please help** I have tried a lot of possible solution but nothing until now

Comment: "There is an error but I can not see it"  -- what is the error message?

Comment: you should be able to de/serialzie the entire `employeeList` at once.  Especially with the BinaryFormatter doing it record by record can be a problem; **then** rather than copying items to the list box just use the employee list as a datasource.  From the picture, it looks like you serialized something other than employee objects - maybe listbox items? Cant say without seeing `SaveData`

Comment: if you check the pic you will de error message

Comment: But the error message (which should be **in** the post) indicates that what you serialized is a different type than that you are trying to DEserialize to.  If we could see SaveData we could tell for sure

Comment: private void SaveData()
        {
            FileStream outFile;
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            if (lstEmployees.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                outFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                for (int i = 0; i < lstEmployees.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    //write on file via serialization
                     bformatter.Serialize(outFile, lstEmployees.Items[i]);
                }
                outFile.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry I did not see the way to saw you the saving method

Comment: [Edit] your post and put the code in the question.

Comment: Its Done now. Thanks lads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Unable to cast object of type System.String to type Assignment.IpayableStaff` pretty clearly indicates you serialized a different type than you are deserializing to.

Furthermore, serializing one record at a time is a bad idea when an entire list can be de/serialized all at once.

Update from comment:  `...bformatter.Serialize(outFile, lstEmployees.Items[i]);` you are serializing `ListBox` objects (one by one), then trying to deserialize them to something else (`IPayableStaff`).  You *may* have stored `IPayableStaff` to `Items` (code we cant see), but when serializing you did not cast them back.

#### Remedy

```
// some data
critters = new List<Animal>();
string file = @"C:\Temp\Animals.bin";

Animal animal = new Animal("ziggy","feline", 3.14);
critters.Add(animal);
critters.Add(new Animal("rover", "canine", 1.23));
critters.Add(new Animal("Gizmo", "muhwai", .56));

SaveData(file, critters);

List<Animal> newALst = LoadData(file);
// use the List<T> as listbox datasource
lb1.DataSource = newALst;
```

Whatever you use in the `ToString()` override on `Animal/IPayableStaff` is what will show in the listbox (and Debug!):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}  ({1})",Name, Species);
}
```

[image]

The Save/Load methods:

```
private void SaveData(string fil, List<Animal> animalList)
{   
    // serialize entire list
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fil, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, animalList);
    }
}

private List<Animal> LoadData(string filename)
{
    List<Animal> newLst = new List<Animal>();

    // deserialize entire list and return it
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        newLst= (List<Animal>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    return newLst;
}
```

The `BinaryFormatter` knows the Type serialized because it writes type meta data to the file.  This results in the error you got and by doing it one by one you can easily trash the file trying to save just one record instead of all of them everytime.

Comment: Thank You very much, I appreciate the help that you have given me, Although it did not work.... but thanks a lot - do not worry I will take it from here and try to find the error and fix it. Thanks Plutonnix